# Why is the mask element not cloned when using <use> element?

Tags: html, svg

In mdn, it says:

> The  element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else. The effect is the same as if the nodes were deeply cloned into a non-exposed DOM, then pasted where the use element is, much like cloned template elements.

However, it seems to not copy `<mask>` elements.

I created an example in the plnkr link below. In the example, I have a mask in the SVG and I am using a fragment identifier to try to clone it, but it's not copying the mask as well. In the shadow DOM, you'll find it completely missing. It's currently showing a black circle, but the expected outcome is to see a heart in the black circle.

https://plnkr.co/edit/6uR4xBAdxqIo7D51?open=lib%2Findex.html&preview

You can find how it should look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask

Does anyone know how to include the mask when using the `<use>` element?

Edit: To address the issue of using plnkr. This bug is only reproducible if the SVG is an external resource and within the correctly calibrated CORs headers.

Comment: Could someone explain why I am getting downvoted?

Comment: Wasn't me; but maybe because you got 65K SO points and not using  a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead linking to a plnkr that can be gone next week

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I don't believe those allow you to upload a separate file. The example I am sharing requires the file to be external and linked within the same domain for CORs reasons.

Comment: @RobertLongson Wow! thanks for sharing that. I can't believe I ran into a bug that is more than 10 years old.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll mark your answer as best if you create one. That is the unfortunate reality of the situation.